Ros2 pub, dds sub, use zero copy
When I use cyclonedds, I send a string using the publisher_member_function of ROS2 and subscribe to rt/topic using pure dds. If SharedMemory is not enabled, I can communicate and receive string data normally. If SharedMemory is enabled, communication is normal, but I receive an empty string。
the DDS side code is as follows:
my String.idl
module std_msgs {
 module msg {
    module dds_ {
        struct String_ {
            string data;
         };

}; }; };  // module msg::std_msgs


and my dds sub code:
#include "dds/dds.h"
#include "String.h"
#include "dds/ddsrt/time.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define MAX_SAMPLES 1

int main()
{
 dds_entity_t participant;
 dds_entity_t topic;
 dds_entity_t reader;
 dds_return_t rc;
 dds_qos_t *qos;

 std_msgs_msg_dds__String_ *msg;
 void *samples[MAX_SAMPLES];
 dds_sample_info_t infos[MAX_SAMPLES];
 uint32_t status = 0;

 /* Create a Participant. */
 participant = dds_create_participant (DDS_DOMAIN_DEFAULT, NULL, NULL);
 if (participant < 0)
   DDS_FATAL("dds_create_participant: %s\n", dds_strretcode(-participant));
 /* Create a Topic. */
 topic = dds_create_topic (
   participant, &std_msgs_msg_dds__String__desc, "rt/topic", NULL, NULL);
 if (topic < 0)
   DDS_FATAL("dds_create_topic: %s\n", dds_strretcode(-topic));
 
 /* Create a Reader. */
 qos = dds_create_qos ();
 dds_qset_reliability (qos, DDS_RELIABILITY_RELIABLE, DDS_SECS (10));
 reader = dds_create_reader (participant, topic, NULL, NULL);
 if (reader < 0)
   DDS_FATAL("dds_create_reader: %s\n", dds_strretcode(-reader));

  dds_delete_qos(qos);

 printf ("\n=== [Subscriber] Waiting for a sample ...\n");
 fflush (stdout);

 samples[0] = std_msgs_msg_dds__String___alloc();
 /* Create a message to write. */

 while(1) {
   /* Do the actual read.
    * The return value contains the number of read samples. */
   rc = dds_take (reader, samples, infos, MAX_SAMPLES, MAX_SAMPLES);
   if (rc < 0)
     DDS_FATAL("dds_read: %s\n", dds_strretcode(-rc));

   /* Check if we read some data and it is valid. */
   if ((rc > 0) && (infos[0].valid_data))
   {
     /* Print Message. */
     msg = (std_msgs_msg_dds__String_*) samples[0];
     printf ("=== [Subscriber] Received : ");
     printf ("Message (%s)\n", msg->data);
     fflush (stdout);
   }
   else
   {
     /* Polling sleep. */
     dds_sleepfor (DDS_MSECS (20));
   }
 }

 /* Deleting the participant will delete all its children recursively as well. */
 rc = dds_delete (participant);
 if (rc != DDS_RETCODE_OK)
   DDS_FATAL("dds_delete: %s\n", dds_strretcode(-rc));

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
